# CDB unable to get callstack from crash dump, but Visual Studio can

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to write a program to automate getting the call stack from crash dumps. It runs cdb.exe:

```
cdb.exe -i "{binaries path}" -y "{binaries path}" -srcpath "{source files path}" -z "{dmp file path}" -lines
```

I then feed some commands to CDB's standard input:

```
.symfix+ c:\\symcache
.ecxr
k
q
```

For many dumps this succeeds in printing the call stack, however some dumps do not work. The dumps that don't work output this error:

```
Unable to load image C:\Windows\System32\igdumd32.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igdumd32.dll
```

However, Visual studio is able to figure out the call stack just fine. In the Visual Studio call stack, igdumd32.dll is at the bottom of the stack:

```
igdumd32.dll!0c70c570()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for igdumd32.dll]
```

I'm not sure if the symbol not loading is the problem or not, but I can't figure out why CDB can't get the call stack while Visual Studio can.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing"
```

Sometimes this means what it says, annoyingly. I've no idea what VS does to get around it. So far the best I have for cdb is to, instead of k, run kd (the cdb command, not kd the kernel debugger program!) to get the raw stack data, then discard the junk lines between the useful ones.

You'll probably want to supply a number of lines (in hex) after kd to get enough output to contain the whole call stack. 
e.g.

```
kd 200
```

Oh, this doesn't work for dumps generated from 64-bit processes because kd uses the wrong word size (afaict this is a bug). I'm currently looking for a way to work around this cleanly. For one thread you should be OK with something like:

```
dps @esp L200
```

This uses the esp register to access the stack, which is not portable but works for me. You may need a different register.